# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 4, 4)

Tags: keras, reinforcement-learning

I try to make a 2048 game that uses **reinforcement learning**. I tried to input a 2D array (matrix), but gets an error when the `dnq.fit()` function is called.

Before this error I got another similar problem, with it `expected 2 dimensions but got (1, 1, 16)` (The reason for 16 is that I flattened the matrix). I resolved it with `.squeeze()`.

I do not know where to fix the code, because I thought I fixed the input shape.
I have looked at similar problems on so, but that did not help.

**Model code**

```
env = GameEnv()

states = env.observation_space.shape
actions = env.action_space.n

def build_model(states, actions):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu', input_shape=(1, 16)))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(actions, activation='linear'))
    return model

model = build_model(states, actions)
```

**Agent code**

```
def build_agent(model, actions):
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
    dnq = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, nb_actions=actions,
               nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update=1e-2)
    return dnq

dnq = build_agent(model, actions)
dnq.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
dnq.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=1)

scores = dnq.test(env, nb_episodes=100, visualize=False)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Keras adds an additional dimension during `fit` because it processes in batches, so you need to add your batch size (or just -1 as keras can automatically infer the actual number) to the front of the `input_shape` in `build_model`

Comment: I do not fully understand where I should write -1. If I specify batch size: 'model.add(Dense(24, batch_size=1, activation='relu', input_shape=(1, 16)))' I get this error: ValueError: Model output "Tensor("dense_2/BiasAdd:0", shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)" has invalid shape. DQN expects a model that has one dimension for each action, in this case 4.